# unrecognized selector sent to instance...again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, segue

I'm currently doing the calculator app that has the graph functionality. So then, I have this button in my Calculator and wired it up on my Calculator2ViewController. Also, I wired this button to another UIViewController named GraphViewController and named the segue's identifier to be `showGraph`. Below is the code for my segue.

```
- (GraphViewController *)graphViewController {
    return [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
}

- (IBAction)graphPressed {

     if ([self graphViewController]) {
     [[self graphViewController] setProgram:self.brain.program];
     }

     else {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showGraph" sender:self];
     }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue.destinationViewController setProgram:self.brain.program];
}
```

There, so no errors and warnings. But when I try to run the app, and press `Graph` button, the app crashes and get this on my console.

```
2012-06-18 11:08:17.272 Calculator2[1135:f803] -[Calculator2ViewController graphPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c38850
2012-06-18 11:08:17.273 Calculator2[1135:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Calculator2ViewController graphPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c38850'
```

Kindly enlighten me with this as to why is this happening and how can I do this on a better way. Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
Changed `- (IBAction)graphPressed` to `- (IBAction)graphPressed:(id)sender`. The segue works now. However, I have this notification on my console (which is kind of scary)

```
2012-06-18 11:30:02.955 Calculator2[1260:f803] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-06-18 11:30:03.308 Calculator2[1260:f803] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-06-18 11:30:03.309 Calculator2[1260:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <GraphViewController: 0x6e458d0>.
```

Comment: In which class you have defined graphPressed ???

Comment: I just wired up my Graph button to the Calculator2ViewController.m and named it as `graphPressed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`graphPressed` and `graphPressed:` are different methods. One has an argument parameter, the other doesn't. You have implemented it as:

```
-(IBAction)graphPressed
```

But you may have declared the function in the header as:

```
-(IBAction)graphPressed:(id)sender
```

Which it (rightfully) sees as two completely separate functions. Now, you can actually declare *and implement* it without any parameters (`-(IBAction)graphPressed`) or *with* parameters (`-(IBAction)graphPressed:(id)sender`) but what matters is that it is **consistent in both declaration and implementation**. The declaration and implementation must be the same.

Just a tip, it is a best practice to always declare IBActions as `-(IBAction)myButtonWasPressed:(id)sender` because this lets you know what button was pressed (via the `sender` parameter) and it allows you to have multiple buttons that fire off the same event and still be able to tell which was pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, really appreciated that. I've done this suggestion and the segue works now. However, I get a notification on my console (refer to edited post). Please help me out with that. I mean, why is it giving me that notification. Also on another note, when I have reached the next VC after pressing the button, when I want to go back to my initial VC it takes 2 presses of back bar button to actually do that instead of just 1.

Comment: You should post those as separate questions.

Comment: Chances are that you've got a push/segue in the code (which I can see that you do) *as well as in the storyboard* (which I can't see) - ie, you might be pushing twice by accident.

Comment: I do also have a push segue in my storyboard. Did that by wiring up my graph button to the next VC. Please suggest how can I solve this in your most convenient time.

Comment: Well, then it's pretty simple then. Remove one. You shouldn't be pushing in the storyboard *and* via code - you should be doing one or the other.

Comment: I removed the `performSegueWithIdentifier` part and now it works fine, free of those messages in console. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See how the selector in the error has a colon?  It looks like the same method, but it's not quite the same...  graphPressed needs to be declared with a param

```
- (IBAction)graphPressed:(id)sender
```

Comment: Thanks! I've done this and the segue is now functioning. However I receive this notification from my console and it's kind of scary (see EDIT in the post)

Comment: My my, comment doesn't look good. I'll edit my post instead and see the notification there.

Comment: Don't see the edit yet.  It could be something going on in setProgram maybe an animation?  Maybe post that code?  I'm going off for the night, but will check tomorrow.

Comment: It's posted now, you can check them out. Thanks